# Chow ring of Fano threefold of index 2

Tags: algebraic-geometry, intersection-theory

Let $Y$ be a Fano threefold of index $2$ with $Pic(Y)=\mathbb{Z}$. I understand that
$H^0(Y,\mathbb{Z}),H^2(Y,\mathbb{Z}),H^4(Y,\mathbb{Z}),H^6(Y,\mathbb{Z})$ are all $\mathbb{Z}$, generated by the classes of $Y$, a hyperplane, line and point respectively. I am looking for a reference that the Chow ring is also $\mathbb{Z}$ in each degree and generated by the cycle as described above.

I know there are group homomorphisms from $A^k(Y)\to H^{2k}(Y,\mathbb{Z})$ for $k=0,1,2,3$, but struggle to prove why they should be isomorphisms.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: For Fano 3-folds,  the integral Hodge conjecture is true, so by Lefschetz (1,1)-theorem and $H^2=H^{1,1}$, $A^*(Y)\to H^{2*}(Y,\mathbb Z)$ is surjective, so your question is to ask if $A^2\to H^{4}(Y,\mathbb Z)$ is injective.

Comment: Are you considering the Chow groups (i.e., cycles modulo rational equivalence), or the Chow groups modulo algebraic equivalence? It is unclear what you mean from the question.

Comment: @Sasha I had cycles modulo rational equivalence in mind, but I would be happy to learn if the isom can be achieved by any variation of it. THanks!

Comment: Another comment: I don’t know if $A^3\to H^6$ is injective (although a necessary condition for injectivity is that $h^{0,p}=0$ for $p\ge 1$, which is satisfied).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\mathrm{CH}^2(X)_{\mathrm{alg}} \subset \mathrm{CH}^2(X)$ be the subgroup of algebraically trivial cycles. Then there is the Abel-Jacobi map
$$
\mathrm{CH}^2(X)_{\mathrm{alg}} \to J(X)
$$
to the intermediate Jacobian, and the Jacobian is generated by the image.
So, if the intermediate Jacobian of $X$ in nontrivial (in the case of Fano varieties of index 2 this happens for $d(X) = H_X^3 \le 4$), the kernel of the cycle class map
$$
\mathrm{CH}^2(X) \to H^4(X,\mathbb{Z})
$$
contains the nontrivial subgroup $\mathrm{CH}^2(X)_{\mathrm{alg}}$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It also seems from the proof of Corollary 5.8 in https://arxiv.org/pdf/0809.0225.pdf that each of $CH^k_{num}$ is the integer group generated by the cycles mention in the original problem. For k=0,1,3 AG learners argument works. and I suppose for k=2,  $Ch^2(X)_{alg}=Ch^2(X)_{num}$ just because $l\cdot H=1$?

Comment: The quotient $CH^2_{num}/CH^2_{alg}$ (more precisely, $CH^2_{hom}/CH^2_{alg}$) is called the Griffiths group, and I am not sure what is known about it. But definitely the equality $l\cdot H = 1$ doesn't say anything about this.

Comment: @RustQ Proof of Cor. 5.8 doesn’t really assume that the assumption of 5.7 is satisfied. As Sasha mentioned, Griffiths group for Fano 3-folds is not much known (although it is expected to be trivial group). For cubic 3-folds, Voisin (last two pages of https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~claire.voisin/Articlesweb/voisingargnanovrai.pdf) showed that if the minimal class on intermediate Jacobian is algebraic, then the Griffiths group is trivial, however, it is not known if a general cubic 3-fold satisfy that condition.